# Using functions like header() and setCookie() after output in a website

Tags: php, http, setcookie

I am developing a website with a login system. If the user logs in successfully, a cookie is set. The code looks a bit like that:

```
if(!success)
    echo "denied";
else
    setCookie(x,x,x,x,x);
```

Now, the problem is that code like this wouldn't work anywhere else than on a local test server (localhost). Now, my question is, are there any standardized ways to work around this? Or does the developer have to write his code so that problems like these don't appear in the first place?

Comment: _'... cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction) ...'_ [PHP: setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: check this link [PHP Cookies with Login](http://bgallz.org/157/php-cookies-with-login-setcookie/#sthash.WZ6KxeQz.dpbs) it will help you

Comment: @user45562 thanks. in fact, i know that thats how it is. i want to know a way to work around that.

Comment: That code should work as it is *either* sending output or setting a cookie. If you do send output before sending a cookie there actually is a workaround which allows the output to be temporarily cached then stored in a variable or sent to the browser afterwards.

Comment: You should check and make sure the actual file encoding. If UTF-8 make sure that it's without BOM otherwise it may send a tiny piece of data to the browser before it even executes any PHP. This is because the engine interprets the first byte as raw Plaintext/HTML to send to the browser. This obviously violates the requirements of header() and setCookie().

Answer (score 4):

You can use use `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush` to activate the output buffering for specific code:

```
ob_start()
< code >
ob_end_flush()
```

or you can activate the output buffering for all your pages from the php.ini:

```
output_buffering = 'On'
```

Comment: I didn't know about that second option but if the first doesn't work it's a BOM issue.

Comment: thanks for that answer. is that just a workaround, or is that the usual way to do this?

Comment: @MartinHoffmann It's a workaround, the usual way is send the headers and cookies before any output. The recommended value for `output_buffering` in a production server is `4096` (default value), it's to reduce packet fragmentation.